# Sharepoint External Content Type authentication mode - what to choose?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

My scenario is simple: i have a list of employees in some database, I would like to display it in sharepoint for everyone to see (read only, no updates).
So I created SQL external content type and then created external list based on it. But I can't get how to handle the autnetication. On creating the external content type you get to choose authentication mode: user's identity, windows impersonated and custom impersonated. I don't want my sharepoint (AD) users to have access to the database so the first option is out. I just want everyone to see the list in sharepoint and I have an sql user and password to get there, but i don't know how to provide it. I've read a lot about the authentication modes but I still don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently faced with a similar scenario, and, after much research here is the procedure I cobbled together:

(1) In SharePoint Designer 2010, create the external content type. For the connection identity information, select "Connect with Impersonated Custom Identity" and for the Secure Store Application ID provide the username that you usually use for database connections. Hopefully the connection is successful.  If it is, set up the ECT the way you want it and save.  If not, you can try one of the other authentication options (or, in my case, I had to connect through a VPN).

(2) After you've created the ECT and it's showing up in the External Content Types list, right-click on it and select "Export BDC Model."  The exported BDC model is just an xml file, which you will edit in step 4 below.

(3) Once you've exported the BDC model, delete the ECT that you just created in SharePoint Designer. From here on out you'll be using the exported BDC model, and if you keep the one you created in SharePoint Designer you'll get a conflict.

(4) Now open up the exported BDC model (it will have extension .bdcm) in a text editor.  Locate the  element (it will say , where "YourDatabase" is your database name). Delete everything between the opening and closing tags of the  element, and replace it with the following:

```
<Property Name="AuthenticationMode" Type="System.String">PassThrough</Property>
<Property Name="DatabaseAccessProvider" Type="System.String">SqlServer</Property>
<Property Name="RdbConnection Data Source" Type="System.String">YOURDATASOURCE</Property>
<Property Name="RdbConnection Initial Catalog" Type="System.String">YOURDATABASE</Property>
<Property Name="RdbConnection Pooling" Type="System.String">True</Property>
<Property Name="RdbConnection User ID" Type="System.String">YOURUSERNAME</Property>
<Property Name="RdbConnection Password" Type="System.String">YOURPASSWORD</Property>
<Property Name="RdbConnection Integrated Security" Type="System.String">False</Property>
<Property Name="ShowInSearchUI" Type="System.String"></Property>
```

Of course, replace the YOUR values with your actual values.

(5) Then, go to the SharePoint Central Admin console, and, under Application Management, click on Manage Service Applications, and then click on Business Data Connectivity Service.

(6) Then, click the Import button (upper left hand corner).  In the import dialog box, browse for the .bdcm file you modified in step 3 above.  For "File Type," make sure "Model" is selected.  For "Advanced Settings," check off all three options (Localized Names, Properties, and Permissions).  Then click the gray Import button.

(7) You should now see your BDC model in the list. Hover over it with your mouse until you see the dropdown menu arrow.  Click on that and select "Set Permissions."

(8) Select the user(s) or group(s) to give permissions to (and be sure to click the "add" button), and click OK. Then hit the add button, and you'll see the possible permissions in the permissions box.  Check off the permissions you want to grant, and then click OK.

(9) Finally, the ECT is ready to use. Go to your SharePoint site, click on Site Actions > More Options, and select External List and click on the Create button. In the Data Source Configuration area, click on the icon to the far right of the External Content Type field ("Select External Content Type"), select the ECT you just set up, and 
click on Create. If all goes well, you should see the data from your SQL database. If there's a problem, you'll get a very unhelpful error message.

I hope this is helpful to someone.